# 500 error when I click buy product

Tags: cart, ajax, prototype-js

I'm having a 500 error when I click to buy a product. I tried to reset folder permissions and I know that it isn't code error because I have production and development enviroment . In my development work. I read that can be a memory error, but this error not occur in development, that have less memory than production.

Please see a screenshot of error, the box don't load anything.

[image: Chrome print error]
[image: Firefox print error]
Thanks

Comment: Please have a look on this great debugging answer and comment back: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: I solved this issue restoring a backup... But I dont found the reason of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the error log for your webserver for clues as to what is triggering the error message.

Error 500 would definitely log what caused the problem.

Comment: I deleted current logs files and repeated the process. But haven't new files created at logs folder.

Comment: Try restarting the web services from your server, sometimes they need to be restarted to commit the logs.

Comment: I tried restart apache when change folders permissions...

Comment: Why was this down voted?